# Inheritance and singleton or static array of objects

Tags: c++, inheritance, dictionary, singleton

I am writing a small programm in C++ and am facing a choice on how I should implement something.

I have found two possible implementation for the particular problem I am facing, and would like your advice on whether one is "better" than the other.

I have a class, let's call it Letter.
I want to create different 'objects' : A, B, C, D...

Each of those objects are going to be used multiple times in my software (as properties for other objects). An A will always be the same so there is no need to create an A object every time I need A.

1. I create a class for each A, B, C... that inherits from Letter. Each of those classes would be a singleton. By doing this, I would be able to use the A object anywhere in the rest of the software by calling the A::getInstance() static method.
2. I create each A,B,C,D as an object of class Letter and store those 4 objects in a static array. Throughout the remaining of my program, I would be using the content of that array. In Order to easily access those objects, I might create an enum and store the objects in a map instead of an array.

Do you think one of those solutions should be preferred to the other ?

As I said earlier, any alternative suggestions are welcome :-)

Regards

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for the [Flyweight Design Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight)

Comment: You have to move away from the 4 singletons no matter what. A singleton is just another global. For sure if you have 4 of them like here. Also the array is not per se fine. Question is if there are dependencies between A, B, C, D. If so they should have references to each other.

Comment: I think a lot depends on how these objects are expected to behave. Do they all operate the same way but on different internal data? Or do they all operate differently? So far what you have described sounds like it might benefit from the "typesafe enum" pattern whereby one class is defined and several static global instances are created (private constructor).

Comment: The idea of the Flyweight Design Pattern seems interesting, I'll have to dig a bit deeper into the concept to see if it would be effective in my case.

Comment: Actually it's not just 4 but more like 20 "objects" that I need.

The thing is these objects will be exactly the same, appart from their attributes, that's why the static array crossed my mind as there is no real difference in how they behave.


The "typesame enum" pattern seems interesting too. If I understand well, with this approach, I would have one class that would store (or generate rather) a number of static instances

Answer (score 0):

Various aspects here that might affect your decision.

Some people don't like singletons because they are global objects and they don't like global objects. If your object should be global then make it global.

Some people think that if you have a singleton object then it should be the only instance of the class. However, if you have several distinct instances of a class, which each behave like a singleton would behave, creating multiple subclasses just to make sure a class has only one instance, that is quite pointless. (An example in Cocoa programming is NSCharacterSet, where you have distinct instances, like an NSCharacterSet representing letters, one for digits, one for letters that are valid as parts of Java identifiers, and so on and so on).

You should only create an array if you want to access the n-th element of the array, and the same statement could refer to different array elements. It looks like you want distinct object with distinct purposes; making them an array would be pointless again.

Comment: Actually appart from their attributes' values, my objects will be identicals (same attributes and same methods). I said array but the map idea would make it more usable.

If I understand well, your point would be to create a sort of Manager class which would be a singleton and contains several static instances, one for each Letter, a bit like what @Galik proposed in his comment above.